# Record exist in another table, before inserting-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel framework so please be patient, I have two  tables the user  and the received_pay tables, the challenge is I want to check in received_pay first for the email and receipt_number if they match with the user input during registration if they match then new user is created otherwise rejected, below is my tables details

user:
id, username, email, remember_token, created_at, updated_at

received_pay:
id, email, receipt_number

my register controllers code for user is:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if (Received_pay::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists()) {
    // user found
        echo "user exist";
     }
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'token'   => $data['token'],
    ]);
```

Comment: Code looks fine, what is the issue, you want suggestion on how you can improve it? or you have any issue ?

Comment: You want to check email and receipt_number together for existance?

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
Received_pay::where('email', $request->email)->exists()
```

to

```
Received_pay::where('email', $request->email)->where('receipt_number', $request->receipt_number)->exists()
```

you can combine multiple conditions by using multiple `where()`

Comment: Thanks it works I upvoted it just no enough reputation

Comment: Doesn't matter, what matter is solution worked for you

Comment: @konzlaugoko now you can upvote and mark as accepted :b

Comment: Note that `Input::get('email')` is deprecated though. Instead, use `$request->email`.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Implemented suggested edits, Thanks for suggestion